# Making last item of listview to scroll till middle of the screen

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I am having a `ListView` . It always has few items say 4 or 5 so it easily fits in the screen.
I am also having some view at bottom of the screen which is transparent.
My issue is the last item of listview is only partially visible because of view at bottom so I want to make that list item also to scroll till middle of the screen so that its details are visible. Any suggestions for doing this.

[image]

Comment: Show your code, it could be easy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this, Use Relative parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_enter_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/editfield_selector"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/next_btn_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="send"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear_footer"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add INVISIBLE footerView which has LayoutParams the same as "Some other view" to your listView.

something like:

View view = findViewById(R.id.other_view);

view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

yourListView.addFooterView(view);